# Java login authentication

Tags: java, authentication, jakarta-ee

Hey there just got some questions i want to validate before i will start implementing login flow on my website.

So basically which way is safer / better / more optimal to do.

Let's get to the point. What I'am trying to achieve is some kind of control panel for administrator, its seperate website which allows to manage very important data.
How i want it work is to make it as secure as possible meanwhile being optimized because data will be displayed live through sockets.
So let's get to the point..
url.com/ is root url, which consists of login panel, I want to hide other page's so no one can access them meanwhile authoriziting users.

Before i start with authorization method i got a question about authentication (not sure if named them right =P)

Which authentication is safer, i send POST with username / password and should i return token which i shall save in sessionStorage and then send token with every request (that's how i did it with my REST API) or should i do it in java with.

```
//validate with db and if valid.
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAtrribute("token",token);
```

So i red a bit and came to this conclusion.

Method no.1 creating a filter for all pages which prevents from accessing them through URL.

```
@WebFilter("/*")
public class LoginFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

        if (session == null || session.getAttribute("token") == null) {
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/");
        } else {
//check if token is not expires or if exists with database
            chain.doFilter(req, res); // Logged-in user found, so just continue request.
        }
    }

}
```

Method no.2 using servlets to map urls and read them from WEB-INF.

```
@WebServlet("/dashboard")
public class SearchServlet extends HttpServlet {
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{

        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/dashboard.html").forward(request, response);
   }
}
```

and reading from WEB-INF would be in doPOST method, with token sent in header Authoriization, if valid then redirect to page from WEB-INF else to login.

If my question is somehow dumb im sorry, i'am 2nd year student and still learning.

Comment: If you're not sure about any of these things, then what you *should* do is use a prepackaged system like Spring Security (which, while I am a big fan of Spring for Web apps, will work with standalone servlets as well).

Comment: It's not like i'am not sure and MAXIMUM security is must-have, it's just that im on learning phase and I would like to taste every approach possible in practice and making good practice's with implementation.

Comment: Why don't use JAAS?

Comment: Did not heard about it =P

Comment: Use Spring along Spring security is the best way, give it a try